# How to get the value of html <input type=“hidden” id="hide"> in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is for generating the table.

```
function makeTable()
{
var row_num = 20;
var cell_num = 4;

var tab = document.createElement('table');
tab.setAttribute('id','newtable');
var tbo = document.createElement('tbody');
tbo.setAttribute('id','tabody');
var cont;
for(var c = 0 ; c < row_num ; c++)
{
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var k = 0 ; k < cell_num ; k++)
    {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        if (k > 0)
        {
            cont = document.createElement("input");
            cont.setAttribute('type','text');
        }
        else
        {
            cont = document.createTextNode("0" + (c+1));
        }
        cell.appendChild(cont);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbo.appendChild(row);
}
tab.appendChild(tbo);
document.body.appendChild(tab);
tab.setAttribute("align", "top-left");
}
```

This function is used to show the data in alert box but I want to retrieve document.getElementById('hide').value............

```
function GetCellValues()
{
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     var str = '';
    for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
    {
        str += '\n';
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
        for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
        {
            str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
        }

    }   
    document.getElementById('hide').value = str;
```

I want to retrieve only this hidden control (i.e-"hide") in php.

```
    alert(document.getElementById('hide').value); 
}


window.onload = function()
{
    makeTable();
};

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1><u>PROJECT</u> :</h1>
      <input type="button" value="Alert" onclick = "GetCellValues()">
```

I want to retrieve this id in php

```
      <input type="hidden" id="hide" /> <br />



      <div id="mytable">
       <table id = "project" border = "1" width ="60%" class = "newtable" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
         <th align="center" width ="200px">Sl.No.</th>
         <th align="center" width ="200px">Project Name</th>
         <th align="center" width ="200px">ChangeDate</th>
         <th align="center" width ="200px">Changed By</th>
      </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
     </body>
```

**Note:** I want to retrieve the hidden control through id in php ##

I want the total php code to retrieve this hidden control data(i.e-input `type="hidden" id="hide"`) because I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a name to your input so for example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="foo" />
```

To retrieve the value in php after POST form submission you can do this:

```
<?php $var1 = $_POST["foo"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace this line

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" />
```

and use `$_POST["hide"]` in you php script.

Answer (score 0):

Input field must have some `name` to access it

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" />
```

do normal fetch

```
$name = $_POST['hide'];
```

Answer (score 0):

add name property to input type and value you want to get into you php

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="flag" value="1" />
```

and to retrieve the value in php after POST form

```
$var1 = $_POST["flag"];
```